How do I edit the "add user" page?
I know very little about Drupal.  My company has a Drupal 10 website that I'm trying to learn how to navigate.
When I create a new user, it opens a page admin/people/create with "Add user" at the top and various fields for creating the new user profile.  On this page there's a drop-down that specifies the user's preferred language.  I'm trying to edit this.
Unlike most other Drupal pages, there's no overall "Edit" tab for this page, nor are there any widget-level Edit options.  I've tried searching through the menus for Structure, Views, Taxonomy, Blocks, etc., but I can't find anything that seems to represent this page.  I also can't find any information online, since all of my searches give results for how to edit user profiles, which I can already do.
How can I edit the "Add user" page?  Small words are appreciated :)
Edit: I've figured out how to get to the admin/config/people/accounts/fields/user.user.field_language/storage page, but this presents a new question that Stack Exchange won't let me post separately.
The contents of the "Allowed values list" entry box on that page are key|label pairs like
english - american|American English
english - british|British English

I assume the key portion of each line has to match one of a set of pre-existing keys.  How do I determine what this set is?  Specifically, if I want to add a new language whose key already exists, how do I find what that key is?

What is it about the drop-down you wish to change? That will be vital for a fact-based answer.

I want to add an entry

@monalisa See edit to question.  I've figured out where to edit the list, now I'm trying to figure out what the allowed keys are for the list.

From the field ID in the URL, user.user.field_language, you can infer that this is a custom field, i.e. one not created by core.
The core language field doesn't have editable values, and the fact that you see the Allowed values list makes it pretty likely that this custom field is a List (text) type.
As such, those "allowed values" are completely arbitrary; they don't necessarily relate to anything that exists in Drupal, or more to the point, anything that you have control over through the UI. They also might. There's no way to tell from just looking at the UI (unless the original developers also built you a relevant UI, of course).
You only really have two options here:

Ask the original developers what those string are, what they relate to, and how to manipulate them
Get an unrelated developer to go through the relevant parts of the code/database to get you an answer

